# The MIME type of the selected file is not allowed

Tags: apex, data-loader

When I am trying insert data using .csv file from Data Import wizard in salesforce, I am getting this error "The MIME type of the selected file is not allowed". My csv file contains a single column with Account names.

I tried to upload the another file still I got the same error, I used "" and , for field separator and deliminator.

Any help in resolving this error will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try this? Copy and paste the whole list of account names in Editplus, open a fresh excel sheet, copy back the list from editplus and paste it in the excel sheet. Then save the sheet as CSV.

Comment: Thanks, That worked! can you please tell me what was the issue with the file?

Comment: Sometimes some hidden characters get copied/added to the file restricting file being the usable format. I am adding this as an answer. Please accept it as others could also refer it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this? Copy and paste the whole list of account names in Editplus, open a fresh excel sheet, copy back the list from editplus and paste it in the excel sheet. Then save the sheet as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same example when working through a tutorial on Trailhead (import contacts_to_import.csv)

Being a Mac user I thought that this might be the issue, but it proved much simpler: switch from Firefox to Chrome! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox (I tried 41.x) on Windows/Mac shows the MIME-Type error - seems to be an Firefox bug.

I switched to Chrome and it works!