# Error while uploading files to a custom object via import wizard?

Tags: data-import-wizard

I am trying to upload files of CSV type via Import wizard but I am getting the following error

> The MIME type of the selected file is not allowed.

There was  a similar post with the same issue [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/62644/the-mime-type-of-the-selected-file-is-not-allowed) but I am not able to use it since I am working with ubuntu which doest support "edit plus"

Note:The problem comes only after the recent update.,But still I am not very sure about it.

Any suggestion?Thanks.